# Should I get 7 or 21 speeds for city commute?

Tags: gears, hybrid-bike, 7-speed

I'm 5'10" 95kgs and am looking to buy a hybrid cycle for exercise.

Have never ridden a geared bicycle before and was wondering if I should go with 7 or 21 gears.

My commute would be within city roads with occasional flyovers.

Comment: But how steep are the flyovers? And indeed the normal roads. A bigger range of gears  mainly helps with climbing

Comment: Is the '7 speed' you're considering a derailleur or an internally geared hub?

Comment: 7 speed comes with a derailleur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

7 and 21 gears are functionally the same at the back.  The difference is whether you have one or three chainrings on the front.

For simplicity, a 1x7 would have less stuff and therefore be more reliable.

Consider that your biggest climb is a "flyover" which will likely have a maximum grade of 5% and a maximum height of 15-20 metres.  Worst case its a moment's walking if you can't pedal up yet, and that will come over time.

The main difference is "spacing" between the gears.  A 3x7 will likely have a lower-low and higher high gear.  Does that matter for your need?  Probably not.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll be going with the 7 speed one for keeping things simple